# Does spectrochemical series trend depend on the metal center?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Can the trend of spectrochemical series vary/fluctuate according to the central metal atom (CMA) that is being used?

For example, for the CMA $\ce{Ni^2+}$ the ligand $\ce{H2O}$ will have more CFSE than $\ce{NH3}$ because $\ce{NH3}$ acts as a weak field ligand (WFL) for $\ce{M^2+},$ even worse then $\ce{H2O},$ though $\ce{NH3}$ is placed higher then $\ce{H2O}$ in the spectrochemical series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectrochemical series of ligands, our instructor clarified, gives *only a rough idea* of the *relative strengths* of ligands, and may vary for different Central Metal Atoms (CMAs).

An important example that I have encountered is of $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^+^3}$, wherein $\ce{H2O}$ acts as a Strong Field Ligand (SFL), despite its lower position in the series.

Also, JD Lee mentions in his *Concise Inorganic Chemistry (5th ed., Wiley publications)* that there is an increase in CFSE as we go down the group in d-block, and several instances may be found where the ligands designated as WFL begin to act as SFL for 4-d or 5-d members.

Overall, I believe there *are* certain deviations from the series, but it *generally* works well.